# How to save values into one list to iterate in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have been trying to learn the looping and listing in Python. I have a data set which comes from a for loop.

```
listing = []
 try:
        for coordinates in g.objects(None, predicate=URIRef('http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#generatedAtCoordinates')):
            final_coordinates = coordinates
            data = final_coordinates.split(",")
            latitude = float(data[0])
            longitude = float(data[1])
            calc_distance = (latitude, longitude)
        listing.append(calc_distance)

 except ValueError:
        final_coordinates = 0

 print(listing)
```

the calc_distance value is:

```
(41.403277274422436, 2.0966085137374164)
(41.4018032171552, 2.094118204776835)
(41.4031599745838, 2.09554506488234)
(41.40939182891685, 2.092649778368276)
(41.40498153943922, 2.092998814485954)
(41.40134146772367, 2.0950656171373985)
(41.40741149037425, 2.0911841596351013)
```

These are bunch of random coordinates.

I want to save them all into one big list to be able to iterate. The idea is to calculate the distances between them.

The printing of `listing` looks weird:

```
[(41.406975300145035, 2.091861990302946)]
[(41.406975300145035, 2.091861990302946), (41.40113308262795, 2.091383862874567)]
[(41.406975300145035, 2.091861990302946), (41.40113308262795, 2.091383862874567), (41.40599600376296, 2.0947715310666606)]
[(41.406975300145035, 2.091861990302946), (41.40113308262795, 2.091383862874567), (41.40599600376296, 2.0947715310666606), (41.408565289702246, 2.0903512224468255)]
```

It should look like:

```
[(41.403277274422436, 2.0966085137374164), (41.4018032171552, 2.094118204776835), (41.4031599745838, 2.09554506488234)]
```

So from this list, I want to be able to select the first one, and calculate the distances between other coordinates.

I don't know Python, but in Java, there is an iterator function, that goes through the list one by one and puts the value automatically. something like `object.next` I want first value to be stable but second coordinate will change till the end of this list.

for example :

```
print(geopy.distance.distance(calc_distance[1], calc_distance.next).km)
```

Any idea how to do this in Python3?

Comment: You apparently put your `print(listing)` *inside* the loop, so that it prints once per iteration, each time with one more element being in the list than the last time.  Unindent the `print` so that it lines up with the `for`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried unindent as well, it is the same result.

Comment: I updated the code the way how believe I did it. This seems to me out of the loop

Comment: can you show us the results of `print(latitude)` inside of the loop?

Comment: it shows the latitude value, one by one `41.40669669938007
41.40362922649583
41.40796500198342
41.402031046547755
41.403128467631326
41.404730777456884
41.406639273237886
41.409320388183545
41.40396550306589
41.40005136675153`

Comment: I create a pair of latitude and longitude in the algorithm which are stored in the calc_distance variable. So that I can use them to calculate the distances from a geopy.distance.distance algorithm. `coords_1 = (41.43737599306035, 2.1302325410348084)
coords_2 = (41.42535528994254, 2.1898592767949556)

print(geopy.distance.distance(coords_1, coords_2).km)`

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  The code you have given (assuming the print statements you provided are accurate) works properly for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the iteration of the second through last of the `listing` list's coordinates using `slicing` in python:

```
from geopy import distance

listing = []
try:
    for coordinates in g.objects(None, predicate=URIRef('http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#generatedAtCoordinates')):
        final_coordinates = coordinates
        data = final_coordinates.split(",")
        latitude = float(data[0])
        longitude = float(data[1])
        calc_distance = (latitude, longitude)

        # each value from list of coordinates will be appended to 'listing' if it
        # is inside the 'for' loop.
        listing.append(calc_distance)

except ValueError:
    final_coordinates = 0

# create new list with all values from 'listing'
# except first coordinate pair.
sliced_listing = listing[1:]

# first coordinate pair in 'listing' will be compared to 
# each value in sliced list.
for coord_pair in sliced_listing:
    print(distance.distance(listing[0], coord_pair).km)
```